# URL of update method in RestAPI, sending object as a query parameter to it

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have this method in a RestAPI, what is the URL of the method update? How can I send a user parameter to test this method with Postman?

```
@Path("/resource")    
public class MyResource{

@PUT
@Path("edit")
public Response update(@PathParam("id") id , @QueryParam("user")User user){
...
...
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url will be /resource/edit/{id} in your case.

But, I would rather recommend you to define the @Path to your update() method as @Path({id}). Hence, the url will be /resource/{id}.

This will be the url for all your CRUD operations with specific HTTP method type. For example,

```
/resource/{id} - with HTTP GET to get details
/resource/{id} - with HTTP POST to create a new record
/resource/{id} - with HTTP DELETE to delete the resource
```

You can pass the User object in the request body as below in postman(thro' Form-data/raw).

{"firstname":"abc","lastname":"xyz"}

Comment: and in Postman in url should i write : /resource/40 ?       for update the user which it's id is 40

Comment: yes, and don't forget to change the HTTP method as PUT.

Comment: Thank you. i changed it to put and i write in url /resource/40 and in param-body- i have selected formdata and i inserted the properties name of user in the key and their value in the value. should i write the id again in the form data? but i did not received answer from my update method

Comment: in this case User is @QueryParam?

Comment: No need to pass the id as form data. Ensure that you have changed the code as below. Hope you entered the full URI as http://localhost:8080/resouce/40                                                                         @Path("/resource")    
public class MyResource{

@PUT
@Path("id")
public Response update(@PathParam("id") id , User user){
...
...
}
}

Comment: User is not a query param. Its a payload. Whatever you pass it in the payload will be mapped to your User object. The payload fields and the User properties should match.

Comment: i changed my code like that but in Postman i have not received any response and i have ip and port in url

Comment: Pls check the status code in the postman response area. What are you returning from your update() method? Pls share the code, if you don't mind it. Or you can debug it to find what actually happens.

Comment: status code is 415 Unsupported Media Type. and in my code i have define xml text and json for consume and produce

Comment: Add "Content-Type" header in the postman headers with the value "application/json"

Comment: Thanks. i inserted this header and now i it is sending and after some second i have timeout error

Comment: Thank you so much Ratha, Now it is working. i inserted application/json to the header and i send my request by raw json, and i received the response of method,  Thank you so much for your help, Regards